# Is it possible to assign multiple properties in one call?

Tags: c

In languages like C#, you can do:

```
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject() {property1 = 1, property2 = 2 ...}
```

Is it possible to do this for a struct in C rather than writing assignments one per line?
If I try this in C, I get `error: 'property1' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'constructorArg1'?`

This seems basic, just don't know what to google.

Comment: In C99 you have designated initializers, but I don't know enough about C# to say that they are the same thing.